# How do I get the ghillie suit?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

Sometimes while I play Call of Duty Modern Warfare 3 online, I see people with a ghillie suit to help them blend in to their surroundings. How do I get that costume?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You obtain the ghillie suit by completing the challenges associated with it. "Ghillie in the mist" is what it's called. Or, during a multiplayer session, certain maps give it to you by default. The maps are [Bakaara](http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/Bakaara), [Mission](http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/Mission), [Fallen](http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/Fallen), and [Village](http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/Village).

Source: [Call of Duty wiki on ghillie suits](http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/Ghillie_Suit)